# How to get previous datatable row index when filtering the table

Tags: jsf

I'm getting the row index of datatable using rowIndexVar. It's working...
But when I'm filtering, I have to mantain the original index of row.

For example, if I have the rows:

1  |  A
2  |  D
3  |  D
4  |  B
5  |  A

When I filter by A I want to get:

1  | A
5  | A

But I'm getting:

1  |  A
2  |  A

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="row" var="obj" value="#{objectsList}">
    <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Row" />
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:10%" filterBy="#{obj.CDOCUMENTO}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Doc" />
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{obj.CDOCUMENTO}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What is your PF version?

Comment: I'm sorry, I put it wrong. My JSF is 2.1

Comment: In my oppinion this `rowIndexVar` is the index of the row display, not the index of the underlying object list. (What should happen if you alter the sorting of the table?) - I think you'll have to write your own mechanism to get the index the way you want here.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I have to make it on another way. Thanks

Comment: But why do you need it?